# Bar chart legend adjustments - Chart JS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm new in Chart JS and I have a bar chart with the legend displayed bellow the chart:

```
var data = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Disk C',
            backgroundColor: "#000080",
            data: [80]
        }, {
            label: 'Disk D',
            backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
            data: [90]
        },
        {
            label: 'Memory',
            backgroundColor: "#add8e6",
            data: [45]
        }]
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart");

    ctx.height = 300;

    var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        responsive: true,
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    },
                    barPercentage: 0.5,
                    categoryPercentage: 0.5
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

But the legend should be something like [image: this]:

It is possible to make the colors rectangles much more smaller and the values to be displayed one below another because in my example the labels are displayed in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to customize the default legend in the manner that you are wanting.  Fortunately, however, chart.js thought of this and provided a mechanism for you to generate and style your own legend outside of the canvas object (using regular html/css).

You can use the `legendCallback` options property to define a method that generates your legend html and then call the chart `.generateLegend()` prototype method to place into your page.  Here is what I mean.

HTML for my page.

```
<div style="width:25%;">
  <canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
  <div id="legend"></div>    
</div>
```

Then I define how the legend will look in the 'legendCallback' option property.

```
legendCallback: function(chart) {
  var text = [];
  text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
    text.push('<li><div class="legendValue"><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');

    if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
      text.push('<span class="label">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</span>');
    }

    text.push('</div></li><div class="clear"></div>');
  }

  text.push('</ul>');

  return text.join('');
}
```

Finally, I add the legend html to my page.

```
$('#legend').prepend(mybarChart.generateLegend());
```

As always, here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpJjWK) showing a working solution.  You can change your legend look and feel simply by changing the html that is generated by the callback and using css.

Comment: @Dana was this able to help?